# Advantages of [HandleError] over Application_Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I'm aware there are plenty of questions in **SO** about **Error handling in ASP.NET MVC**.

I see, mostly people are trying to achieve things in three ways:

1. Create a `BaseController` and override the `OnException` method
2. Using `[HandleError]` or custom exception filters.
3. `Application_Error` event in global.asax.cs

The first two ways can't handle all the exceptions and they do only that are raised by action methods/filters, so obviously the third one is going to be the best approach for a global exception handler.

My question is why I should go for `[HandleError]` approach? What benefits it brings that I  can't get through `Application_Error`?

Finally, do I want to take the `customErrors` section serious at all in a MVC application?

Note: My requirement is usual. Whenever an exception occurs, log it and return a custom error page. The custom error page may change depend upon the status code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most obvious is that `[HandleError]` allows you to handle errors differently in different controllers and actions. Its much more elegant than some kind of switch statement in your `Application_Error` handler.

Another benefit is that `[HandleError]` still has access to the controller and all the MVC goodness that comes with it, so you can still return a `View` or call another action. Once you fall out to `Application_Error`, you've lost `ControllerContext` and you don't really have options left to you except to redirect.

Comment: I don't see much reason why someone want to handle errors differently in different controllers and actions. Ok, If I do that logic in [HandleError] then again I want to do that in global.asax right?

Comment: Different error page for mobile? Personalized error page for users? Html fragment for ajax requests? Custom error image for broken image links? Access forbidden error pages for certain controllers? It's not hard to think of reasons to handle errors differently.