# Best approach for 404 error handling in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, http-status-code-404

I am trying to handle 404 page not found exception in mvc and i just want to know the right approach to handle page not found. this is how i handle the 404 page not found exception

```
protected void Application_Error()
        {
            ShowCustomErrorPage(Server.GetLastError());
        }
        private void ShowCustomErrorPage(Exception exception)
        {
            var httpException = exception as HttpException;

            if (httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
            {
                Response.Redirect("PagenotFound");
            }
        }
```

is this the right approach !!!

Comment: Does it do what you want?

Comment: actually yes, if the page not found exception is found, applicaiton_Error method gets called and i redirect it to the pageNotFound controller, is there any better way? i dont know the answer thats the reason i asked question in this forum

Comment: actually i tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420981/how-to-call-a-page-using-icontroller-execute-method-in-mvc but i was not successful to call the page and there was no one to help me with the answer, thats the reason i changes my approach a little

Comment: Read the duplicate to your previous question. "The best way" or "the right approach" is not answerable.

Comment: the duplicate for my previous question is also been asked by me and there was no answer, so i thought to ask another by changing the heading but was marked as duplicate instead

Comment: Yeah so perhaps stop asking new questions, take a step back and read the info provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155306/discussion-between-lijin-durairaj-and-codecaster).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268872/automatically-throw-404-exception-from-action-method-if-entity-object-is-null/42269170#42269170

Comment: @AnimusMiles-Militis this is the eaxact approach which i have used above right