# Returning JSON error message for Task<IHttpActionResult> method

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I have created an ASP.NET Web API that will call a java web service and display some results in JSON. When the java web service is not running, i get the error message as:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The method or operation is not implemented.","ExceptionType":"System.NotImplementedException","StackTrace":"   at ApiClientJavaWebService.Models.RestfulClient.InternalServerError(Exception exception) in C:\Users\attsuap1\Desktop\Server Project\ApiClientJavaWebService\ApiClientJavaWebService\Models\RestfulClient.cs:line 43\r\n   at ApiClientJavaWebService.Models.RestfulClient.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\attsuap1\Desktop\Server Project\ApiClientJavaWebService\ApiClientJavaWebService\Models\RestfulClient.cs:line 36\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()\r\n   at ApiClientJavaWebService.Controllers.AdditionController.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\attsuap1\Desktop\Server Project\ApiClientJavaWebService\ApiClientJavaWebService\Controllers\AdditionController.cs:line 20\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

How do i change this to get the error message to be shown as `{"The server is not running."}`?

**Here are my codes:**

**AdditionClient.cs**

```
public class RestfulClient
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static RestfulClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> addition(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {

        try
        {
            var endpoint = string.Format("addition/{0}/{1}", firstNumber, secondNumber);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**AdditionController.cs**

```
public class AdditionController : ApiController
{
    private RestfulClient restfulClient = new RestfulClient();
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        var result = await restfulClient.addition(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        var resultDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temp>(result);
        return Json(resultDTO);
    }
}
```

Someone please do help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: you get `System.NotImplementedException`. Just find, where you throw it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved what i wanted. I realised that the try catch method should be in the controller class instead of AdditionClient.cs class.

Here are my edited classes:

**AdditionClient.cs**

```
public class RestfulClient
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static RestfulClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> addition(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
            var endpoint = string.Format("addition/{0}/{1}", firstNumber, secondNumber);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     } 
}
```

**AdditionController.cs (Focusing on try catch part)**

```
        try
        {
            var result = await restfulClient.addition(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            var resultDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temp>(result);
            return Json(resultDTO);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var result = @"Server is down";
            return Ok(new { ErrorMessage = result });
        }
```

The result that will be shown on browser is `{"ErrorMessage":"Server is down"}` when the server is not running.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can't the manage throwing exception messages in the server which you want to pull data. So, why don't you just filter the exception;

```
        try
        {
            var endpoint = string.Format("addition/{0}/{1}", firstNumber, secondNumber);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.InnerException.Message == "The method or operation is not implemented")
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me, and yes i can't the manage throwing exception messages in the server which i want to pull data from. What should i do in the //Do something part?

Comment: I am quite new to this i have not done this before. Based on what i have researched, i tried codes such as `return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Server is not running");`                     `return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Server is not running"));` but all these did not work

Comment: What you are want to do if an exception thrown as "The server is not running.". You can log it somewhere or return a response to client. If the application has generic error handling mechanism, throw an exception with a message that you want to display.

Comment: How do i throw an exception with a message that i want to display? I tried this `throw new Exception("server down", e);` however i get all those unnecessary messages and the thing that changed was `"ExceptionMessage":"Server down."`

Comment: How do i get rid of the other errors that is showing ?

Comment: Actually, I can't answer this question because I don't know your solution and codes. Error handling is a very generic case. So, it could be a good start point this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993758/asp-net-mvc-5-error-handling