# Asp.Net MVC 5 Try Catch Not Working in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

This is my **code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ForgetPassword(string Email)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("testing");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json("Error");
    }
}
```

Locally, it goes in catch block, but in IIS it doesn't go in the catch block.

Comment: See [ASP.NET MVC 5 error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21993758/6630084)

Comment: @Jackdaw I'm not using global error handling. All my error is handle inside the controller.

Comment: if its not catching what does the browser show? are you sure youre executing the post version of ForgetPassword???

Comment: @IGeoorge The error is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
I added a logger in catch block and it is confirmed that catch block is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Youll need to add the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in order to get the json after post.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ForgetPassword(string Email)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("testing");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json("Error",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working bro.

So, I added Application_Error in Global.asax. Supposedly the error goes to Catch Block, but it goes to Application_Error.

Comment: check customErrors mode is Off in web.config

Comment: I already fixed the issue. The problem is, in catch block, it has a code that has an error.
That's why **return Json("Error");** is not executing.

Comment: that's not in the code you posted. next time paste full code

Answer (score 0):

OMG. I already found out the cause of the error.

There is a code executing before **return Json("Error");**
That code has an error that why the code is not reaching **return Json("Error");**

Comment: then, you should include all the code that involves the error